# Compile perlbrew with libperl.so versus libperl.a

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl, perlbrew

I've been working on moving some software from RHEL 7 to Ubuntu 22.04.

I utilize Perlbrew. When I built the new 5.36.0 everything seemed normal until I started working on compiling mod_perl for my apache servers.

I built perlbrew with this:

```
perlbrew install perl-5.36.0 --as=perl-5.36.0 -Duseithreads
```

Then I tried compiling mod_perl.
It flopped while trying to use the `libperl.a` library.
I hit an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /perl5/perls/perl-5.36.0t/lib/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.a(op.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `PL_hash_state_w' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
```

I did the googling and I think I'm trying to do a 'make' against a library that is static versus a shared object library? I may have the wrong idea but I'm chasing down this in hopes of solving the issue or finding more info along the way.

How do I set perlbrew install options to compile this as a .so library in Ubuntu just like it is in my previous version in RHEL?

```
/perl5/perls/perl-5.26.2/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so

Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
Release: 7.6
Codename: Maipo

/perl5/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
```

TIA

Perlbrew installed without issues, but apache mod_perl won't compile unless it has a libperl.so versus a libperl.a library. Trying to figure out how I force the installer to create libperl.so versus libperl.a that's in there now.

Comment: Tip: If you want a threaded build you should use `-Dusethreads`.  Not sure what `-Duseithreads` does if anything. At best, it's equivalent to `-Dusethreads`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`INSTALL` from 5.36.0](https://metacpan.org/release/RJBS/perl-5.36.0/view/INSTALL) says:

> **Building a shared Perl library**
>
> Currently, for most systems, the main perl executable is built by linking the "perl library" libperl.a with perlmain.o, your static extensions, and various extra libraries, such as -lm.
>
> On systems that support dynamic loading, it may be possible to replace libperl.a with a shared libperl.so. If you anticipate building several different perl binaries (e.g. by embedding libperl into different programs, or by using the optional compiler extension), then you might wish to build a shared libperl.so so that all your binaries can share the same library.
>
> The disadvantages are that there may be a significant performance penalty associated with the shared libperl.so, and that the overall mechanism is still rather fragile with respect to different versions and upgrades.
>
> In terms of performance, on my test system (Solaris 2.5_x86) the perl test suite took roughly 15% longer to run with the shared libperl.so. Your system and typical applications may well give quite different results.
>
> The default name for the shared library is typically something like libperl.so.5.8.8 (for Perl 5.8.8), or libperl.so.588, or simply libperl.so. Configure tries to guess a sensible naming convention based on your C library name. Since the library gets installed in a version-specific architecture-dependent directory, the exact name isn't very important anyway, as long as your linker is happy.
>
> You can elect to build a shared libperl by
>
> ```bash
> sh Configure -Duseshrplib
> ```
>
> [snip]

So you would pass `-Duseshrplib` to `perlbrew install`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked famously. I was behind on a project and this got me back on track. I sincerely appreciate the instruction. Apologies for taking so long to respond. As soon as I saw it I went on a sprint to the finish line. Thanks again!